# Tengo un problema con mostrar valores en pantalla con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Apenas estoy empezando con este lenguaje, pero cuando quiero mostrar algún valor no me aparece nada, alguna solución?

**Código html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Arreglos</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="arreglos.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código javascript**

```
var amigos = {"Ana", "Juan", "Ismael"};
document.write(amigos[0]);
```

Comment: Los objetos son clave: valor, ahí solo tienes valores lo que denota un array

Answer (score 2):

Estás confundiendo el objeto con un array:

```
> var amigos = {"Ana", "Juan", "Ismael"}
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

Debería ser (para crear un array se usan corchetes):

```
> var amigos = ["Ana", "Juan", "Ismael"]
> amigos[0]
"Ana"
```

Con esto claro, probamos de nuevo:

```js
// arreglos.js
var amigos = ["Ana", "Juan", "Ismael"]; 
document.write(amigos[0]);
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="arreglos.js"></script>
</body>
```

Tus amigos:

```js
// arreglos.js
var amigos = ["Ana", "Juan", "Ismael"]; 
document.write("Mis amigos son: " + amigos.join(', '));
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="arreglos.js"></script>
</body>
```

¡Funciona!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es `JQuery` para que te muestre automáticamente el resultado

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var amigos = ["Ana", "Juan", "Ismael"];
    document.write(amigos[0]); 
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Arreglos</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="arreglos.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ademas de que declaras mal el array, cambia las llaves por corchetes.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos me funciono!!! no se como etiquetarlos si no les diera las gracias a cada uno..

Comment: @Fernando, pues si uno de estos te ayudo marcalo como respuesta, de esa forma ayudaras a otros que tengan el mismo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Solo para agregar, el metodo join() se une a los elementos de un array y devuelve una cadena, los elementos son separados por un separador especìfico, el separador predeterminado es ",".

```js
// arreglos.js
var amigos = ["Ana", "Juan", "Ismael"]; 
document.write("Mis amigos son: " + amigos.join(', '));
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="arreglos.js"></script>
</body>
```